# Magento : How to add new field on cart page for take extra info

Tags: php, jquery, magento, shopping-cart, cart

I want to add two custom field on my magento site cart page. Something like bellow screenshot.

[image]

I want to add this two field on the Cart page and this field input i want to display in the Order and Invoice. I have Also use FME extra field extension but its use for the checkout page only.

So please suggest me if any good extension or good link using which i can set this functionality.

Please help to out from this problem

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Jalpesh how are you?, how familiar you are with the Magento code because to get what you want need to extend a little code and use some Observer to add this info to Order and then to Invoice...

You can start using this extension, [Magemaven OrderComment](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magemaven-ordercomment.html).

I hope this can help.
Best,
GrinGo.